# Automation for filling in sets of numbers in each row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to populate the same number 10 times in a row, then the next number up on the next row.

starting at 0, ending at 1000

for example:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
....
1000 1000 1000 1000 1000
```

and to 1000

I need to print out these numbers to cut up and put each row of numbers in each envelope to be sold for a Chinese auction at a benefit.

How do I do this dynamically without entering in all of the rows by hand?

Answer (score 2):

Just enter first two rows manually. Then select all 1s and 2s and start dragging from the right-bottom corner of the selection downwards. You selection will be expanded with values automatically filled with incrementing 1s and 2s downwards.

Answer (score 1):

Enter four cells like this:

```
1 1
2 2
```

Select all four cells and drag right to fill your first two rows.

Now select these two rows and drag down.

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, you actually only have to fill in the first 2 cells. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the address box (just left of the formula bar), type `A1:J1000`, <kbd>enter</kbd> (this will select your 10 columns, 1000 rows), type`=row()`, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You're done.